# Error in eglInitialize() using PyOpenGl (err = 12296)

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, egl

I am trying to set up a headless render on my NanoPi M1 Plus with Mali400 GPU using PyOpenGL with EGL. When I run eglInitalize I get the following error:

Error:

```
  File "ferb_gpu_1.py", line 22, in <module>
    if not eglInitialize( display, major, minor):
  File "/home/fa/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 402, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
  File "/home/fa/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/error.py", line 232, in glCheckError
    baseOperation = baseOperation,
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 12296,
    baseOperation = eglInitialize,
    cArguments = (
        <OpenGL._opaque.EGLDisplay_pointer object at 0xb603f800>,
        c_long(0),
        c_long(0),
    ),
    result = 0
)
```

Here is the code I have written:

```
if not os.environ.get( 'PYOPENGL_PLATFORM' ):
    os.environ['PYOPENGL_PLATFORM'] = 'egl'

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = '0.0'

if os.environ.get( 'TEST_NO_ACCELERATE' ):
    OpenGL.USE_ACCELERATE = False

display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
if(display == EGL_NO_DISPLAY):
    print("Failed to get EGL display! Error: %s", eglGetError())
    exit()

major,minor = ctypes.c_long(),ctypes.c_long()
if not eglInitialize( display, major, minor):
    print("Unable to initialize")
    exit()
```

Comment: Isn't the whole point of using EGL to get an OpenGL context _without_ an associated display (aka headless)? Why would you need to set `DISPLAY` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I was using `os.environ['DISPLAY'] = '0.0'` but it should have been `os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Lost of time wasted with this issue in Ubuntu 22.04 with Nvidia drivers. The solution mentioned by @AdishRao didn't work at the beginning. But then I updated the Nvidia drivers to version `535.54.03` and it worked like a charm.
It also works with `os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'`.
The environmental variables must be set absolutely before importing `OpenGL` or any other module that imports it.

```
import os

# if not os.environ.get("PYOPENGL_PLATFORM"):
os.environ["PYOPENGL_PLATFORM"] = "egl"

os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0"
# os.environ["EGL_DEVICE_ID"] = "0"

import OpenGL
```